# (Seemingly) identical code running completely differently

Tags: java

I've recently been trying to use Visual Studios code and was working on a small challenge concerning scanners. Unfortunately, I got error messages when I tried to run my code. But, When I created a new folder and copied and pasted the code it ran without any errors. I'm pretty confused and was wondering if anyone could explain to me why this is.

Code with errors:

```
public class Hello World{
    
import java.util.Scanner;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {        
 
    
    final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int[] array = new int[10];    


  
    System.out.println("Enter your phone number");
    int inputinfo;
    inputinfo = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

errors:
[Errors given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfLRm.png)

working code:

```
public class Hello World {
               
import java.util.Scanner;
 
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        
 

    final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int[] array = new int[10];    
       

    
    System.out.println("Enter your phone number");
    int inputinfo;
    inputinfo = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

[Full Coding Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/booyz.png)

(also thanks for reading my post)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Your "working code" is 100% identical (except some irrelevant whitespace changes) to your "code with errors" and fails with the same errors. Also, the code in your screenshots doesn't match the code you posted your question. And lastly, please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `import` statement needs to put outside of the class. you can't change the order here, it's always:

```
package my.packagename;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Phone {

  // the implementation of the Phone class

}
```

That's what the first error tells us: delete the token `import` because it's not expected to be at that place in the code.

For the second error, you tried something like

```
public class Hello World {
  // ...
}
```

A class name must not contain spaces. `HelloWorld` would be ok while `Hello World` is not.